# How can I do this in Flutter Testing

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, widget, widget-test-flutter

I'm new to Flutter testing and was hoping If you could help me. I've a class called AddShimmer that looks like this ->

```
AddShimmer(
          child: ListTile(
            title: buildLoadingAnimation(context),
          ),
        ),
```

Now, I'm trying to write a flutter test just to check if a child widget is being passed to the AddShimmer class. To do that, I'm writing something like this ->

```
testWidgets('Shimmer has a child widget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    const childWidget = ListTile(
      title: Text('Loading'),
    );
    await tester.pumpWidget(
     const AddShimmer(child: childWidget)
    );
    expect(find.byWidget(childWidget), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

While I'm executing the test, I'm getting an exception which says ->

```
The following assertion was thrown building ListTile(dirty):
No Directionality widget found.
ListTile widgets require a Directionality widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a Directionality ancestor was:
  ListTile
```

What does it mean and how to test this out ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically flutter needs some additional context in order to render the widget. I usually just wrap it in a `Scaffold` inside a `MaterialApp`.

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  const MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: AddShimmer(child: childWidget),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Got it! DO i need to do this for every test case that I write ?? I mean for all the widgets out there ? All wrapped within the Scaffold and material app?

Comment: Some basic widgets like `await tester.pumpWidget(Container());` don't seem to need the additional context. Also, if the widget already has a `MaterialApp` and `Scaffold` inside it, it would not need to be wrapped inside another  `MaterialApp` and `Scaffold`. So it depends.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help :) Really appreciate it.

Comment: I should note that you could instead wrap `AddShimmer(child: childWidget)` in a `Directionality` widget, as the error message suggests, but then you will get another error saying it needs to be inside a `Material` widget, and then inside a `MediaQuery` and so on.  Wrapping in a `MaterialApp` and `Scaffold` just happens to be easier in my experience.